# What is the best method to find the highest subview that contains a cgpoint?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

Is there a faster method than looping through a uiview's subviews and testing cgrectcontainspoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like [hitTest:withEvent:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/hitTest:withEvent:) will do what you want.

The doc says that it traverses the view hierarchy calling pointInside:withEvent on each subview, which probably ends up calling CGRectContainsPoint, so it's probably no faster.  I'd probably still try it rather than looping through the subviews manually.

Comment: I wen ahead and wrote a custom method to traverse the subview array and record the highest hit.

Comment: @DonWilson could you please share it here?